# Typescript: convert an object to yaml and ignore some propeties of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using typescript to convert an object to yaml. In converting, I want to ignore some properties in object. For example, the object is defined as:

```
A {
    B
    C
}
```

There are two properties `B` and `C` in object `A`.
When converting it to yaml, I want to ignore property `B` and the yaml should looks like:

```
A:
  C
```

Is there any a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Some questions: Do you want to exclude `C` at a known path, or all Cs anywhere?  Do you know all of the structure of `config` or do you want something that is generic for all possible configuration shapes.  JSON is valid YAML - does the YAML need to be in any particular format or is the output of `JSON.stringify` valid?

Comment: Hi @SeanVieira Thank you for your reply. I want to exclude `C` at a known path. What does structure of `config` mean? I think yaml is needed in my scenario.